# localStorage in angular and with objects

Tags: angularjs, object, local-storage

This is a simplified version of my code, however what i need to be able to, is store the output of each input field in localStorage, without them overwriting eachother.

Atm, it doesnt even work. I have to fill both inputs for it to save anything.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("IndexController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  this.list = {
    "mandag":   {},
    "tirsdag":  {}
  };


  //LOCALSTORAGE
  this.Save = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("Ret", JSON.stringify(this.list.mandag));
  }

    this.addFood = (day, title) => {
      this.list[day] = {
        "food": title,
        "ingredients": []
      };
      console.log(this.list);

    }

 
  this.removeFood = (day) => {
    this.list[day].food = "";
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" >
    <div ng-controller="IndexController as vm">
        <div ng-repeat="(day, item) in vm.list track by $index">
          <h3>{{day}}</h3>
          <form class="" name="ret" ng-submit="vm.addFood(day, vm.newFood[$index]);vm.newTodo[$index] = ''">
            <input placeholder="Ædelse" type="text"  id="foo" ng-model="vm.newFood[$index]" ng-disabled="item.food" value="" required/>
            <button ng-disabled="ret.$invalid" ng-click="submitted=true; vm.Save()" ng-hide="submitted">Go</button>
          </form>
          <button ng-click="vm.removeFood(day); submitted=false" ng-show="submitted">X</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    
  </body>
```

[Codepen version](https://codepen.io/Curzey/pen/gGKxeK)

Comment: what's the real problem your "Go" button is disabled untill you fill both input right?

Comment: Try the codepen. It's only the respective Go button thats disabled.

Comment: If you want to prevent them from overwriting each-other you just need to save them as different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the ng-click="vm.Save()" in the HTML, and rearragning my javascript a little:

```js
    this.Save = () => {
      localStorage.setItem("Ret", JSON.stringify(this.list));
    }

    this.addFood = (day, title) => {
      this.list[day] = {
        "food": title,
        "ingredients": []
      };
      console.log(this.list);

      this.Save(); 
    }
```